# Can I generate Some enemies from different positions every time when the game Starts?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How can I generate enemies from different positions on every time the games starts in corona . . . Any one can guide me ...? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you know how to create random numbers in Corona, and your problem is that the same ones keep appearing each time you run your program. The solution you're looking for is:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
```

That will ensure a different result each time.

- [math.random](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/mathrandom)
- [math.randomseed](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/mathrandomsed)
- [os.time](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/ostime)